# Invoke-Command doesn't work but Get-Service does

Tags: powershell

I'm having a bit an issue invoking a command to remotely turn off services via PowerShell.  I'm successful when using

```
(Get-Service -Name tomee -ComputerName servernamefqdn).Stop()
```

However when using

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName servernamefqdn -Credential $creds -ScriptBlock {
    (Get-Service -Name tomee).Stop()
}
```

I get errors

> enter-pssession...winrm cannot process

and

> The following error occurred while using Kerberos authentication: Cannot find the computer servernamefqdn.

I'm using my own credentials to pass in invoke.  I've already ran the quick config for WinRM and added trusted sites for all.  I'm not understanding why the first command works but the invoke command doesn't seem to find the server.  The goal is the script will remotely stop services using another account. I read 1 other person having this same issue but no real solution for me.  Any ideas?

Comment: I forgot to menion that this server is on another domain B but has a 2 way trust.  I'm able to rdp into using domain A creds.  Perhaps something special has to be done in this case.

Comment: [Starting](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/jonjor/2009/01/09/winrm-windows-remote-management-troubleshooting/) [points](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/10/05/troubleshoot-winrm-with-powershellpart-1/).